# How to make Ajax auto refresh <div> tag on page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am using this script to get new comments via ajax. However, the setTimeout method does not seem to work because my content does not refresh every 4000 milliseconds. Any advice? When i remove the document.ready(function)({.....});  it does not load my page at all also

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    function updateMsg() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "/recent/messages/{{ chat.key.id }}",
           cache: false,
           success: function(html){
                $("#chatcontent").html(html);
           }
        });
    setTimeout('updateMsg()', 4000);
    }
    updateMsg();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`setTimeout` fires only **once** after the specified timeout.</strike>

You need to invoke `setInterval()` to repeatly call a method.

However, your `url` looks invalid also. Those `{ }` and whitespace character are not allowed in a query string. Furthermore, you should pass in a method as first argument to `setTimeout` and to `setInterval` aswell.

```
setInterval(updateMsg, 4000);
```

---

After formatting your code, I have to correct myself. You're calling `setTimeout` within `updateMsg()` and that *should* work. So I guess, it's just the problem with your query-string. However, you still should pass in a method to `setTimeout`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function updateMsg() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "/recent/messages/" + chat.key.id,
           cache: false,
           success: function(html){
                $("#chatcontent").html(html);
           }
        });
    setTimeout(updateMsg, 4000);
    }
    updateMsg();
});
```

Comment: @Andy url: "/recent/messages/{{ chat.key.id }}" does work because i am using django python...i could get the initiate messages. but i just cant get the refresh going..so i think it should not be the case of my url..

Answer (score 1):

Actually it looks like the code above would work, as the function updateMsg() is being called initially and then setTimeout is called at the end of that function every time.  I suspect it's the **url parameter** that's wrong.

jAndy is right, the code is better written as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function updateMsg() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "/recent/messages/{{ chat.key.id }}",
           cache: false,
           success: function(html){
                $("#chatcontent").html(html);
           }
        });
    }

    setInterval(updateMsg, 4000);
});
```

Additionally,I'd suggest you use the $.load() method instead of $.ajax:

```
$('#chatcontent').load("/recent/messages/{{ chat.key.id }}");
```

Comment: my url manage to get initial messages though. How could that be wrong then?

Comment: So your initial Ajax call goes through but not subsequent calls? It sounds like the second call to setTimeout() isn't getting called, which means there might be a javascript exception.  Are you using chrome developer tools or Firebug in Firefox to see any javascript errors? Can you see the Ajax requests going through?

Also try the setInterval method and see if that fixes things.

Comment: i tried your setInterval method but it doesnt work either.. yup it does not go through on subsequent calls.firebug seems fine,no javascripts error..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var div;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        div = $('#chatcontent');

        setInterval(updateMsg, 1000);


    });


    function updateMsg() {

        //alert("hello");       

        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            cache: false,

            success: function(html){

            $(div).append(html);

        }

        }); 

    }
</script>

<div id="chatcontent">hello</div>
```

Comment: what is going here? :( would you like to explain?

Comment: @pivotal developer well, function `updateMsg` is running on interval `1sec`, and chat content is being appended on every `1s`